# To determine whether stored procedure has cached plan or not

Tags: sql-server, caching, stored-procedures

I am testing on one stored procedure, to see whether SQL Server can make a "cache plan" for it.
In this stored procedure, it contains "dynamic sql" syntax(using "EXEC"), and supposes that sql server won't store a cache plan.
I used ADO.NET to call this stored procedure, and found the result in sql server.

The following pic shows the result from what I search in "sys.dm_exec_cached_plans" table after executing the stored procedure.

[image: CachedPlan]

Does that mean this stored procedure is being cached for any similar search?
why there is no "query_plan" value in the result?

The sql server is SQL 2014 Enterprise Edition.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that you're using sp_executesql? I would assume there's plan for the rest of the procedure, not the dynamic part, which of course can use an existing prepared plan too, if it exists.

Comment: Hi @JamesZ, I used "EXEC" instead of sp_executesql in the stored procedure. I checked the value in "text" part of the result, and it contains "EXEC" part......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your dynamic sql to reuse the cached execution plans use [`sp_executesql`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx) , If you read the MSDN documentation for sp_executesql it clearly states that sp_executesql can reuse the execution plan and Exec/Execute doesn't.

sp_executesql also allows you to parameterise your queries and protect you against sql-injection attacks.

### From MSDN

> To execute a string, we recommend that you use the sp_executesql
>   stored procedure instead of the EXECUTE statement. Because this stored
>   procedure supports parameter substitution, sp_executesql is more
>   versatile than EXECUTE; and because sp_executesql generates execution
>   plans that are more likely to be reused by SQL Server, sp_executesql
>   is more efficient than EXECUTE.